# Making particles grow while sticking to an object

Tags: particles, physics

I've already got the grow part down, where the particles will grow independently (using a particle texture). I need these particles to stick to my object while it moves.
Using the "No" option for physics on particles will make them stick to the object, but only the Newtonion, Boids, and Fluid options will allow the particles to grow separately over time. But with any of those 3 options selected, the particles are then separated from the object, making them sit still and disconnect from the object as it moves. I need the particles to act like bubbles on the surface of the object. Haven't found a good solution so far.
[image: particle object]

Comment: How about turning of *Emitter Normal* Velocity and *Gravity* to stop the particles from moving, but still be able to use the functionality of Newtonian etc.

Comment: That's what I've done. It's the right direction but not the complete solution. Serge L laid it out pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *Hair* type instead of *Emitter* in Particle settings (suits all kinds of mesh deformations including armatures), it also provides object instancing.

Or stay with *Newtone* option, but use Lattice + Hook combo (for simple scale/rotate/locate animation).

**Prepare Lattice**

Add Lattice object, scale it in object mode a bit bigger than your mesh Cube. Change interpolation to *Linear*.

**Hooking**

Go into Lattice *edit mode*, select all vertices and press Ctrl H, select *Hook to new object* (Empty will be added)

**Setting emitter object**

Add *Lattice modifier* after *Particle system* and select your lattice object.

**Animating**

Now if you try to move Empty, it will engage movement for Lattice and also emitter as it is cotrolled by lattice object. So instead of animating emitter object, animate Empty.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand how hair could be used exactly in the way I needed, but the lattice solution was 100% what I needed. I made the empty x-ray and parented the actual cube to it while leaving the separate emitter object as it is.

Comment: Hair type can render objects as well as simple Newtone emitter, but it works with deformations if enable "Use modifier stack" in particle system.